# How to parse JSON in plsql?

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I am trying to parse JSON in Oracle PLSQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure1 AS
     dato   VARCHAR2(10000);
     je     json_element_t;
     jo     json_object_t;

BEGIN
  dato := '{"NOM03_BOKIDN":"CGM50","NOM03_BOKIDN":"CGM50",
            "NOM03_BOKIDN":"SPV55","NOM03_BOKIDN":"CGM40"}';
  je := json_element_t.parse(dato);
  dbms_output.put_line(je.to_string);
END procedure1;
```

and result is

```
{"NOM03_BOKIDN":"CGM40"}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is not clear enough and should be edited to clarify what you exactly like to know, where exactly is your problem. Perhaps this guide [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is helping you. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? A minimal level of JSON support was introduced in Oracle 12R1 and much expanded in 12cR2.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON payload will not evaluate properly.... Try putting it into something like
http://json.parser.online.fr/.... You will see that the JS Parse will give you the same as you are getting out of the PLSQL.

You probably (not 100% sure because I don't know your use-case) want something closer to this

```
  jo := json_object_t('{"TEST":[{"NOM03_BOKIDN":"CGM50"},{"NOM03_BOKIDN":"CGM50"}, {"NOM03_BOKIDN":"SPV55"},{"NOM03_BOKIDN":"CGM40"}]}');
  dbms_output.put_line(jo.stringify);
```

That will give you an output of

```
 {"TEST":[{"NOM03_BOKIDN":"CGM50"},{"NOM03_BOKIDN":"CGM50"},{"NOM03_BOKIDN":"SPV55"},{"NOM03_BOKIDN":"CGM40"}]}
```

you can then grab the array using json_array_t and loop through it ect.